# libvorbis audio decode from memory in C++

Tags: c++, oggvorbis, vorbis

Given an encoded buffer in C++, what would be the steps using oggvorbis structs to decode the already in-memory data?

OggVorbis_File cannot be used, because assets are within compressed archives.

I'm trying to research the necessary structs and methods, but I'm fairly new to audio encoding and decoding.

Any resources that can help further my reading are appreciated as well!

I should clarify, I intend to use the decoded data to stream into OpenAL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Answering my own question.

This can be done by providing custom callbacks to vorbis.

```
struct ogg_file
{
    char* curPtr;
    char* filePtr;
    size_t fileSize;
};

size_t AR_readOgg(void* dst, size_t size1, size_t size2, void* fh)
{
    ogg_file* of = reinterpret_cast<ogg_file*>(fh);
    size_t len = size1 * size2;
    if ( of->curPtr + len > of->filePtr + of->fileSize )
    {
        len = of->filePtr + of->fileSize - of->curPtr;
    }
    memcpy( dst, of->curPtr, len );
    of->curPtr += len;
    return len;
}

int AR_seekOgg( void *fh, ogg_int64_t to, int type ) {
    ogg_file* of = reinterpret_cast<ogg_file*>(fh);

    switch( type ) {
        case SEEK_CUR:
            of->curPtr += to;
            break;
        case SEEK_END:
            of->curPtr = of->filePtr + of->fileSize - to;
            break;
        case SEEK_SET:
            of->curPtr = of->filePtr + to;
            break;
        default:
            return -1;
    }
    if ( of->curPtr < of->filePtr ) {
        of->curPtr = of->filePtr;
        return -1;
    }
    if ( of->curPtr > of->filePtr + of->fileSize ) {
        of->curPtr = of->filePtr + of->fileSize;
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int AR_closeOgg(void* fh)
{
    return 0;
}

long AR_tellOgg( void *fh )
{
    ogg_file* of = reinterpret_cast<ogg_file*>(fh);
    return (of->curPtr - of->filePtr);
}
```

Usage

```
ov_callbacks callbacks;
ogg_file t;
t.curPtr = t.filePtr = compressedData;
t.fileSize = compressedDataSize;

OggVorbis_File* ov = new OggVorbis_File;
mOggFile = ov;
memset( ov, 0, sizeof( OggVorbis_File ) );

callbacks.read_func = AR_readOgg;
callbacks.seek_func = AR_seekOgg;
callbacks.close_func = AR_closeOgg;
callbacks.tell_func = AR_tellOgg;

int ret = ov_open_callbacks((void *)&t, ov, NULL, -1, callbacks);

vorbis_info* vi = ov_info(ov, -1);
assert(vi);

/* compressed data is available to use, to uncompress look into ov_read */
```

A Special thanks to the Doom3 GPL source for most of the help with this, it can 
be viewed at : [here](https://github.com/TTimo/doom3.gpl/blob/master/neo/sound/snd_decoder.cpp)

Comment: Also you can checkout http://svn.xiph.org/trunk/vorbis/examples/decoder_example.c

Comment: Great answer! Do you happen to have a minimal full working example that I can play around with?

Answer (score 3):

You also can don't reinvent the wheel and use [`fmemopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html) like this:

```
FILE* memfile = fmemopen(data, len, "r");
```

Where `data` is pointer to memory beginning and `len` is length of your data. Then pass `memfile` to `ov_open` like regular `FILE` object.

However, there is downside: this function seems linux-specific (but it can be found in arduino, so I'm a bit confused about its status), so you don't have it on other systems. But there is some implementations for them (check [libconfuse](https://github.com/martinh/libconfuse/blob/master/src/fmemopen.c) for window or for [apple OSes](https://github.com/tmm1/fmemopen)).

Comment: We don't have this on Windows, though.