# oggvorbis file reading from memory

Tags: c++, memory, ogg, vorbis

Im struggling to play ogg files in my test application. Files are encrypted so to be "more" secure I have to read them from memory after decryption. (That doesn't matter I just explained why I need them to read from memory)

I know that I have to create custom callbacks. I've tried to do my own callbacks or edit one that I found ([callbacks that I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437422/libvorbis-audio-decode-from-memory-in-c)). Sadly they doesn't work, reading seems to be fine, but decoding causes segfault.

Just for your information I can play ogg from files, and my en\decryption doesn't coruppt files.

Comment: Did you try debugging/getting a backtrace for the segfault?

Comment: AR_readOgg causes it line with memcpy